# Extract specific info from xml stored in clob

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery

I have a long xml stored in a CLOB and i want to get specific data from the xml, I am using this code:

```
    SELECT t.id, x.* FROM testSSF t,XMLTABLE ('/root/test[@id="2"]' PASSING xmltype(t.xml)
    COLUMNS testname VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'testname' ) x
    WHERE t.id = 2;
```

I am getting this error:

```
   ORA-19114: error during parsing the XQuery expression::  
   ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
   PLS-00201:  identifier 'SYS.DBMS_XQUERYINT' must be declared
   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Please translate to English.

Comment: error durante el análisis de expresión = ORA-19114: error during parsing the XQuery expression, line 1 column 13, the identifier: 'SYS.DBMS_XQUERYINT' must be declared line 1 column 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Clob holds complex XML; how to select specific data with Xquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147095/oracle-clob-holds-complex-xml-how-to-select-specific-data-with-xquery)